# range.setStart & range.setEnd is not getting called more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check the below code where I am trying to implement a facebook like autocomplete feature.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIM5SFP0Z1XK

Here I am first calculating the value of current cursor position along with the character typed. If the character typed is "@" then it will set the value of a field "last_detected" value to the position of the last detected "@", then in the next typed character, it will calculate the offset of last typed @ character and the current typed character, the value between these offset is then passed to the  call_search_function() which will return the complete matched value.

Next, I am calling the replacer function which will replace the partial typed string(the value between offset of last typed @ character and the current typed character) to the complete matched value.

Now the issue is, In my code, this logic is working only once. for example if you type "@und" for the first time, it will replace "@und" with "undertaker" in the contenteditable div but if you type again "@und" it will not work. Please assist.

While debugging the code, I suspect that the below range function is failing when called at the second time.

range.setStart(sel.focusNode, startIndex);
  range.setEnd(sel.focusNode, endIndex);

Any help or assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code please. I am doing this and that does not really help us to understand what is wrong.

Comment: @serdar.sanri : Please check. I have posted my entire code in this link - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIM5SFP0Z1XK